# Another way for global variable in Ruby and Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I am using Ruby and Sinatra for my application.

I want to assign a variable which will be used in different classes and methods.

In my app file ie 'Millennium' is my app name so the application file is `millennium.rb` contains :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'yaml'
require 'active_record'
require 'sidekiq'
require 'statsd'

custom_statsd = Statsd.new('localhost', 8125)  #custom_statsd available across the application. 

class Millennium < Sinatra::Application
  set :use_queueing_in_dev, false # useful for debugging queue issues.
  set :protection, :except => [:json_csrf]

  configure do
    # These allow our error handlers to capture the errors
    disable :raise_errors
    disable :show_exceptions
    enable :logging
  end

  before do
    #logger.info request.body.read
    request.body.rewind
  end
end
```

Here I want to use value of `custom_statsd` variable in any class of my application.

I think using "$" is not a good idea. Please suggest me what is the other way to do this.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 6):

It might be marginally better to put the instance in a class variable in a shared config module, like so:

```
module MyAppConfig
  def self.statsd
    @statsd ||= Statsd.new('localhost', 8125)
  end
end

class SomeOtherThing
  def log!
    MyAppConfig.statsd.something('hey')
  end
end

SomeOtherThing.new.log!
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a global variable in general is not recommended but in certain circumstances it is the simplest so the best way, just don't overuse it.
I recommend using a single constant as a namespace here, initialised from a yaml config file.

```
CONFIG = YAML::load_file("./config.yaml")

to_monitor CONFIG.monitor.osign_job_id
```

here the config.yaml

```
--- !ruby/struct
  zf: 999
  debug_level: DEBUG # available log levels are: DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR and  FATAL 
  :monitor: !ruby/struct
    osign_job_id: 86
```

Comment: Hey Jesper, and why not ?

Comment: My two cents: For one, it's unnecessarily cryptic. There are other solutions that would make more sense to the next developer who sees the code. Keeping global config in a module is a common ruby pattern. Also: although this particular use case is probably safe, YAML is a common attack vector for hackers. Better not to get into the habit of using it. If a config file is needed, there are more benign data formats.

Comment: cryptic ? my collegues non programmers often update these parameters but they would be scared to update modules, being code an not configuration files and I would bet yaml is more used as common Ruby pattern than the use of Modules for configuration but of course all this is opiniated and both are usable, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) module of Ruby, and create a class to wrap the instance of `Statsd` for use across your app.

```
require "statsd-ruby"
require "singleton"

class MyStatsd
    attr_accessor :statsd
    include Singleton
    def initialize
        @statsd = Statsd.new 'localhost', 8125
    end
end

p MyStatsd.instance.statsd
#=> #<Statsd:0x0000000281f180 @host="localhost", @port=8125,...
```

**NOTE:** `instance` method will construct the object on first call, however, it does not accept any parameters, hence, we cannot pass parameters to constructor of `Statsd` - thus having to hard code the values `localhost` and `8125` in the constructor of `MyStatsd` -  you may have to find another way to get those values from YAML config or something to make your code generic.